# Who is the head of Ravenclaw?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

We're pretty familiar with the heads of the other houses:

- The Head of Gryffindor is McGonagall
- The Head of Hufflepuff is Sprout
- The Head of Slytherin is <s>Slytherincess</s> Snape, then Slughorn

**But who is the head of Ravenclaw?**

Comment: This is a very poorly researched question. Simply googling the title of this question gives one the answer directly.

Comment: @rah4927 I reckon I was actually faster than google ;)

Comment: @rah4927 Perhaps, but the first several hits are from wikia, a mildly trustworthy site.

Comment: @CandiedMango I really really doubt that. Given that the number of words in your answer is a lot more than the number of keywords one needs in order to find the answer on google, it's not possible for you to have been faster than google.:-)

Comment: @DaveJohnson I don't know a lot about the reliability of wikia. Nevertheless, i don't think it is possible for a website to have mistaken that. Besides, there have been plenty of instances in the books from where one can infer who the head of the Ravenclaw house is.

Comment: @rah4927 You are seeing the final edit though, the first was only the first line. Then I posted. Then found some proof and another interesting fact.

Comment: @rah4927 Many questions on this site can be answered directly from the books, that does not make them a bad question.  I have read the books all at least half a dozen times, and had no idea that Flitwick was the head of Ravenclaw.

Comment: @rah4927 I have read the books at least half a dozen times and watched the movies about a dozen times; forgive me for forgetting the detail and asking a question on this site. You could ask a Star Trek question that I think is poorly researched, but I know a lot about Trek. Furthermore, the day this site begins accepting the Harry Potter wiki on face value is a sad day for us all!

Comment: @N_Soong, asking a question about a thing that you have forgotten is not a problem. The problem is that the question was poorly researched and can be answered through googling. However, I must admit that I always seemed to find it obvious that the head of the Ravenclaw house was Flitwick. But I can't find a direct reference to him being the head of the house, though there are  many instances where one may infer it.

Comment: Found a direct reference in the books. In the chapter "Birthday Surprises", the trio take the apparition test in book-6. It was directly mentioned that he was the head of the house. "...assembled in front of Professors McGonagall, Snape, Flitwick and Sprout-the Heads of the House-...."-Half Blood Prince.

Comment: @rah4927 if it's a poor question because it can be answered by googling, then that makes **a lot** of the questions on this site poor questions!

Comment: @N_Soong I guess this discussion is making this thread unnecessarily off-topic, but it's not a poor question because it can be found on google, but because no attempt was made at researching it and that googling it gives you a head-start on answering the question anyway. But let's not take this any further. After all, comments are not for extended discussion, and there seems to be no point in taking this to a chat. :-)

Comment: @rah4927 agreed 

Comment: I agree with Dave that this is a good question, because even if you can find the answer with some googling, it's not so easy to find the actual proofs for this in the books.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Filius Flitwick is the head of Ravenclaw.

> Hogwarts Charms professor and Head of Ravenclaw house
>
> [Pottermore - Character Profile - Filius Flitwick](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/filius-flitwick)

Interestingly Filius and Minerva both had a similar experience with the sorting hat which featured opposite outcomes, Minerva into Gryffindor and Filius into Ravenclaw.

> After five and a half minutes, the Sorting Hat, which had been vacillating between the houses of **Ravenclaw and Gryffindor, placed Minerva in the latter**. (In later years, this circumstance was a subject of gentle humour between **Minerva** and her colleague **Filius Flitwick**, over whom the Sorting Hat suffered the same confusion, but reached the opposite conclusion. The **two Heads of house** were amused to think that they might, but for those crucial moments in their youths, have exchanged positions
>
> [Pottermore - Writing by JK - Professor McGonagall](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/professor-mcgonagall)

Comment: OMG - how did I not remember that!  +1 for the insanely fast response

Comment: Always here for the HP reminders! @N_Soong

Answer (score 12):

We see that it's Flitwick in at least *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*:

> "Thank you, Hagrid," said Professor McGonagall, standing up at once and turning to look at the group around Bill's bed. "I shall have to see the Ministry when they get here. Hagrid, please tell the Heads of Houses — Slughorn can represent Slytherin — that I want to see them in my office forthwith. I would like you to join us too."
>   [...]
>   "Rosmerta?" said Professor McGonagall incredulously, but before she could go on, there was a knock on the door behind them and Professors Sprout, Flitwick, and Slughorn traipsed into the room, followed by Hagrid, who was still weeping copiously, his huge frame trembling with grief.
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, chapter 29</sub>

Since we know that Sprout is Hufflepuff's Head of House, and Slughorn was just said to be Slytherin's, that leaves Flitwick as Ravenclaw's.

We also see a more direct mention earlier:

> When Harry and Hermione arrived in the Hall (Ron had come down with Lavender), they found that the tables had disappeared. Rain lashed down against the high windows and the enchanted ceiling swirled darkly above them as they assembled in front of Professors McGonagall, Snape, Flitwick, and Sprout — the Heads of Houses — and a small wizard whom Harry took to be the Apparation instructor from the Ministry.
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, chapter 18</sub>