# Who becomes Head of House if there is no teacher from that house?

Tags: harry-potter

We know from [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166909/was-it-required-at-hogwarts-that-a-head-of-house-have-been-a-student-in-that-hou) question that all the Heads of Houses that we've seen were sorted into that house when they were students.

My question is, what happens if there is no teacher at Hogwarts from that house? Does a teacher from a different house take the responsibility or does the headmaster *have* to go around and look for a teacher from that house?

Comment: This seems very opinion-based. The author was very careful to make certain that this eventuality didn't arise

Comment: Although the novels don't discuss it, there's a chance that Rowling answered the question in an interview or an article.

Comment: There is only a 3 point something chance that an unbiased random selection of 12 teachers will lack someone from a particular house. It is highly possible that it has simply never been a problem.

Comment: This question does not seem to be Primarily Opinion Based. There does not seem to be any reason why there couldn't be a perfectly factual answer to the question. If you know Harry Potter so well that you know that there is no answer, then that is the answer.

Comment: Indeed, and even if the answer is "we don't know", [there's nothing wrong with that](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11330/31394).

Answer (score 1):

I think that Headmaster appoints one. Headmaster probably ensures that there are teachers from every house just for that eventuality.

Comment: This seems a reasonable answer given the hypothetical nature of the question.

Comment: But the question is _what if there isn’t_. (And I think the answer is still _the Headmaster appoints one_, even if the appointee is not of the house. Being a teacher is not the same as being a student.)